# How to declare Closure function in PHP extension?

Tags: php, c, php-extension, php-internals

I learning php extension write in C.

Now i meet code below, i want to declare a Closure function.

How to achieve this in a PHP extension?

```
class myClass
{

    public function removeListener($event, $listener)
    {
        // some code
    }

    public function once($event, callable $listener)
    {
        // How to declare the closure and contain the use grammar features?

        $onceListener = function () use (&$onceListener, $event, $listener) {
            $this->removeListener($event, $onceListener);
            call_user_func_array($listener, func_get_args());
        };

        $this->on($event, $onceListener);
    } 


    public function on($event, $listener)
    {
        // some code
    }

}
```

@**NikiC** Thanks for your comment.

I'm try use the `zend_create_closure` API below.

```
static void once_listener_handler(INTERNAL_FUNCTION_PARAMETERS)
{
    // How to get variables from syntax `use(&$onceListener, $event, $listener)` here.
    // And use these variables like `php_var_dump(zval);`.


    RETURN_TRUE;
}


zend_function mptr;
mptr.type = ZEND_USER_FUNCTION;
mptr.common.arg_info = NULL;
mptr.common.num_args = 0;
mptr.common.required_num_args = 0;
mptr.common.prototype = NULL;
mptr.common.scope = NULL;
mptr.internal_function.handler = once_listener_handler;

zend_create_closure (once_closure, &mptr, NULL, NULL TSRMLS_CC);
```

I got error below.

```
/mac/sourcecode/php-5.5.23/Zend/zend_hash.c(1055) : ht=0x9f8c69 is inconsistent
/mac/sourcecode/php-5.5.23/Zend/zend_hash.c(551) : ht=0x7ffff7e0e6c8 is inconsistent

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000009f7740 in zend_mm_check_ptr (heap=0x1333ee0, ptr=0x7ffff7e12150, silent=1,
    __zend_filename=0xfa7b38 "/mac/sourcecode/php-5.5.23/Zend/zend_hash.c", __zend_lineno=568,
    __zend_orig_filename=0x0, __zend_orig_lineno=0) at /mac/sourcecode/php-5.5.23/Zend/zend_alloc.c:1384
1384        if (p->info._size != ZEND_MM_NEXT_BLOCK(p)->info._prev) {
```

Can your show some code snippet for `zend_create_closure`?

And try to use some variables in `internal_function.handler` callback that pass by call place context.

Thank your :)

Comment: Do you want an actual closure, or only some kind of callback? If you need a real closure, look at the zend_create_(fake_)closure API to create a closure from an internal function.

Comment: the posted code looks like C++ not C.

Comment: @NikiC  I had update the question content. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @0X07DE Why are you doing `mptr.type = ZEND_USER_FUNCTION`? Your function is not a user function, but an internal function.